# react render Logical && vs Ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, conditional-operator

In the react `render()` when the value of x equals 1 both the logical && and ternary operator will display ***Hello*** and both are syntactically correct. I always used the && when I don't want to show the else part of my condition, but I have come across one code base where most of the places they used ternary operator with ***null*** instead of &&. Is there any performance gain or any other advantage of using one method over the other?

```
return (
    <div>
        <div>{x === 1 && <div>Hello</div>}</div>
        <div>{x === 1 ? <div>Hello</div> : null}</div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: if your condition uses strict (or loose comparison) you're good with the `&&` operator. If you simply check for a truthy value, e.g. `x && <div>Hello</div>` you would render `0` if `x` potentially ends up using that value. A common scenario would be to check the length of an array, where you probably don't want to render anything in case of empty array, but end up rendering `0` instead

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's no significant performance difference, but because `0` and empty string `""` are ["falsy" in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) I always opt for the ternary operator so the next person to edit my code knows my exact intention.

Example:

```
const count: number | null = 0;
const firstName: number | null = "";

return (
    <div>
        {/* Was this a bug or is `0` really not supposed to render??
          * This will just render "0". */}
        <div>{count && <>The count is {count}</>}</div>

        {/* Okay got it, there's a difference between `null` and `number` */}
        <div>
          {count == null ? <>No count at all</> : <>Count of {count}</>}
        </div>

        {/* Was this a bug too or is `""` supposed to render nothing?
          * This will just render an empty string. */}
        <div>{firstName && <>My name is {firstName}</>}</div>

        {/* Okay now I see `null` / `undefined` vs. a string */}
        <div>
          {firstName == null ? <>No name</> : <>This *will* render {firstName}</>}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Hello Ross,


But wouldn't this behave as expected and easy for the next person to understand ?

    <div>{firstName==null && <>My name is {firstName}</>}</div>

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any performance gain

The answer is NO.

In React Js, It's called [[Inline If with Logical && Operator]](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

> It works because, in JavaScript, **true && expression always evaluates to
> expression**, and false && expression always evaluates to false.
>
> Therefore, if the condition is true, the element right after "`&&`" will
> appear in the output. **If it is false,** **React will ignore and skip it.**

Comment: This just quotes the React docs, and therefore doesnt illuminate the truly subtle gotchas that other answers address and that the OP wants to comprehend. 

Another reason this answer doesnt really help is that I actually think the React docs could be clearer in explaining the gotcha—which examples above and below of unintentionally rendering a "0" or an empty string lay out—that comes from using `&&` rather than a ternary.

Answer (score 5):

Great question. This a React gotcha, more than a performance problem. The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator), in my opinion, just dont make this clear enough, and Ross Allen's answer is right on and hints at that, but let me try to clarify even more.

**If you have *any* doubt that your conditional could evaluate to a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)**—such as `array.length` (and thus react will render an array length of zero) or the string rendered could be an empty string—**use the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**!

**Otherwise you can use the `&&` operator freely and confidently.** An example would be something like

```
count && count > 3 && (
  <div>In stock</div>
)
```

The above check will either be true or false. So you're safe. Note that we ALSO checked to make sure `count` is truthy first *and then* we checked the conditional we're looking for specifically. That way we eliminate the possibly of a falsy value being rendered unintentionally.

Another example:

```
data?.order_type && data.order_type === 'patient' && (
  <div>For patients</div>
)
```

This will also only be true or false. Note I also included the `?` as an [optional chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). This is shorthand in JavaScript that allows you condense some of your truthy checks. `data?.order_type` checks that `data` is truthy first, and if it is, the evaluation continues, otherwise it will exit the evaluation.

**When to use the ternary:**
If your conditional could evaluate to a falsy value. For example:

```
items.length ? ( // length could be 0
  <div>available</div>
  : null
)
```

However if you change the above to `items.length > 0`, then you're good to with `&&` operator.

```
items.length > 0 && ( // length could not be 0
  <div>available</div>
)
```

**When in doubt, make your checks more specific and be sure you're thinking falsy/truthy when you're dealing with conditional rendering.** It is a gotcha, but once you get the idea behind it, it all makes more sense.

Comment: `count && count > 3 && (<div>In stock</div> )` 
 will return `0` if `count` is `0`

Answer (score 3):

No performance gain, just easy to format.

```
    <div>
        <div>
            {x === 1 ? (
               <div>Hello</div>
            ): null}
        </div>
    </div>
```

And if you want to deal with else part later, modify little

```
    <div>
        <div>
            {x === 1 ? (
               <div>Hello</div>
            ): (
               <div>just change here.</div>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is advised to use `ternary operator` instead of logical `&&`, `||`. There is a major difference if you do not take it into account. You can read the details in the below article.

[Kent Blog About this](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/use-ternaries-rather-than-and-and-in-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no performance advantage. So its up to the developer to know the different rules and exceptions that could happen.

To make it simple my rule would be:
Use ternary operator for every case BUT when I am sure my variable is always a boolean

```
 const [shouldDoSomething, setShouldDoSomething] = useState(false)
```

Here my state will always be boolean if I just toggle it
Then:

```
<>

    shouldDoSomething && <Something/>

<>
```

For any other case ternary will do it.