# When to use ternary operator over the logical operator in React to render conditionally only when there are items

Tags: reactjs, logical-operators, conditional-operator

I have to (conditionally) render some React JSX markup, only when it contains items (from api).

```
 return items?.length ? (
  <div>
    <MyBlock data={myBlockData} />
  </div>
  ) : null;
```

But what's the difference between a Ternary null operator (like above) or a Logical operator like:

```
 return items?.length && (
  <div>
    <MyBlock data={myBlockData} />
  </div>
  );
```

What to use in my case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react render Logical && vs Ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65713434/react-render-logical-vs-ternary-operator)

Comment: Check out the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference is between what JSX will get constructed when you have false(y) condition.

The ternary operator will return `null` and therefore nothing shows up on the DOM node, whereas in case of logical operator, the false(y) value will evaluate to 0, and therefore, you'll see "0" getting added as a text node in your DOM.

If you wish to use the logical operator to conditionally render, it's always better to add a fallback.

```
return items?.length&& (
   <div>
     <MyBlock data={myBlockData} />
   </div>
  ) ||
  null;
```